# How do you convert from a string to an int in Java?

Tags: java, string, int

So I have to make a card project that takes a string such as "Six of Hearts" and converts that into an integer array based on the value of the number (six) and the suit (hearts). I'm hitting a wall as to how to get java to take the string "six" and output 6... Any hints?

Edit: 
    Clubs = 0;
    Spades = 3;
    Hearts = 2;
    Diamonds = 1;

Comment: use a switch statement.

Comment: With difficulty. Although in this simple cause, create a `Map<String, Integer>` of lowercase values. Then simply use `Map.get`.

Comment: What's the value of the "*number*" Ace or King?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is typically something you would use an enum for:

```
enum Suit{
 CLUBS   ("clubs", 0),
 DIAMONDS("diamonds", 1),
 HEARTS  ("hearts", 2),
 SPADES  ("spades", 3);

 private final String name;
 private final int value;
 private static final HashMap<String, Suit> suitByName;
 static {
    suitByName = new HashMap<String, Suit>();
    for (Suit s: Suit.values()){
        suitByName.put(s.name, s);
    }
 }

 Suit(String name, int value){
     this.name = name;
     this.value = value;
 }
 public int getValue(){
    return this.value;
 }

 public static Suit fromString(String card){
    return suitByName.get(card.toLowerCase());
 }
}
```

Code for card values omitted. Follows the same approach.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a Map.  You could also use a case or if else statements to accomplish this.

```
    HashMap<String, Integer> numbers = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    numbers.put("ace", 1);
    numbers.put("two", 2);
    numbers.put("three", 3);
    numbers.put("four", 4);
    numbers.put("five", 5);
    numbers.put("six", 6);
    numbers.put("seven", 7);
    numbers.put("eight", 8);
    numbers.put("nine", 9);
    //etc...
    HashMap<String, Integer> suits = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    suits.put("clubs", 0);
    suits.put("spades", 3);
    suits.put("hearts", 2);
    suits.put("diamonds", 1);

    numbers.get("zero");//use this to access the number
    suits.get("spades");//use this to access the suit
```

Case sensitivity will matter here so make sure the key matches whatever you pass to access the value...

Comment: Might want to mention that the OP should use `String.toLowerCase`.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways you can do this, but in my opinion the simplest way would be to have a map of  where the string key is the word for the number, i.e. "six", and the value returned is the integer value.

So your code would look like this

```
HashMap<String, Integer> numMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
numMap.put("two", 2);//repeat for all numbers
```

then whenever you need the digit, you do `numMap.get("two")`

Comment: The ever popular One of Spades?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch absolutely, you've never used it?

Comment: @CBredlow I use it all the time; now tell me the rules of this *poker* again?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch You've never heard the expression "I've got a one up my sleeve?" Isn't it also part of the dead man's hand?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch see, two 8s and two 1's! But in other news, I fixed my code to use 2 instead of 1 as the example.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch curses, fixed!

Answer (score 0):

You can mix it up a little bit.

1. Split the input string into array of string. B. In the resulted
2. Array at index cell 0 it will contain the Number. C. In the resulted
3. Array at index cell 2 it will contain the Shape.

Now all that you need is to convert Number into actual number. This can be achieved by `Switch` or `Map`.

The same goes for converting Shape into actual number that represent the shape.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, based on finding the index of an element within an array:

```
String str = "Six of Hearts"; //input string
String[] numbers = new String[]{"zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "jack", "queen", "king", "ace"};
String[] suits = new String[]{"clubs", "diamonds", "hearts", "spades"};
String[] name = str.split(" ");
if (name.length != 3) throw new Exception("Improperly formatted card name");
int value = Arrays.asList(numbers).indexOf(name[0]);
int suit = Arrays.asList(suits).indexOf(name[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Enum is very useful in this kind of scenario ..  [See Documentation.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

First Create an Enum of CardValue eg. `ACE TWO..`

```
enum CardValue {

        ACE(1),TWO(2),THREE(3),FOUR(4),
        FIVE(5),SIX(6),SEVEN(7),EIGHT(8),
        NINE(10),TEN(10),JACK(10),QUEEN(10),KING(10);

        private int cardValue;

        private CardValue (int cardValue){
            this.cardValue = cardValue;
        }

        public String toString(){
            return String.valueOf(cardValue);
        }

    }
```

Second Create an Enum of CardSuit eg. `HEARTS CLUBS..`

```
    enum CardSuit {
        DIAMONDS(1),HEARTS(2),SPADES(3),CLUBS(4);
        private int cardSuit;
        private CardSuit(int cardSuit){
            this.cardSuit = cardSuit;
        }

        public String toString(){
            return String.valueOf(cardSuit);
        }

    }
```

Then try this one.

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String inputedCard = "Six of Hearts";

        //Converts inputed card to uppercase then split it.
        //so the expected value is aInputedCard[0] = SIX & aInputedCard[1] = HEARTS
        String [] aInputedCard = inputedCard.toUpperCase().split(" OF ");

        //So you just need to Verify if the input is in correct format to avoid exceptions

        System.out.println("["+CardValue.valueOf(aInputedCard[0])+"]["+CardSuit.valueOf(aInputedCard[1])+"]");

    }
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you can use [`Integer.parseInt(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)).